# Silverlight grid: left should stretch, right is defined

Tags: silverlight, xaml, grid

I'm trying to make a grid for a listitem template. There should be three columns, the second and third columns should be 50px wide each, the first column should stretch too fill the rest of the empty space.

Here's my code so far:

```
<DataTemplate x:key="NoteItemTemplate">
 <Grid Background="{Binding ColorBrush}"
   Height="50"
   Margin="5,5,5,5"
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

      <!-- far away, in an another file.. -->

 <ListBox
    x:Name="NotesListBox"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    ItemsSource="{Binding NotesList}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NoteItemTemplate}"
    Background="AliceBlue" />
```

Makes no difference if it's 1* or *.

But I can't seem to find the answer. How would you do it?

Comment: Changing the `1*` to just `*` should do the trick.

Comment: @Slugster: 1* and * are equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to use the above Grid definition as DataTemplate for an ListBoxItem. By default, the content of an ListBoxItem is not stretched, so that in your case you will only see 2 columns.

So I think you need to specify, that you want to stretch the content of the ListBoxItem. Do it like so:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Is there a way to write this in the data template? Or does it have to be in the listbox?

Comment: No the DataTemplate is not the right place and it is not possible to do that. You can define a style for the ItemContainerStyle in a central resource dictionary and reuse it for your ListBoxes